# Making word index with loop and lists only

Tags: python, loops, indexing

```
fhand = open ("foodtips.txt", 'r')
fhand1 = open ("foodtips.txt", 'r')

count = 0

lines = fhand.readlines()

fhand_text = fhand1.read()

fhand_text1 = fhand_text.replace (".", "")
fhand_text2 = fhand_text1.replace (",", "")
fhand_text3 = fhand_text2.replace ("'", "")
fhand_text4 = fhand_text3.replace ("(", " ")
fhand_text5 = fhand_text4.replace (")", " ")
fhand_text6 = fhand_text5.replace ("-", " ")
fhand_text7 = fhand_text6.lower().strip()
fhand_text8 = fhand_text7.split()

wordlist = list(set(fhand_text8))


for i in range (len(lines)) :
    appeartimes = []
    for word in wordlist :
        if word in lines [i] :
            appeartimes.append(i)
        print word, appeartimes
```

Hello, everyone. I'm new in Python and currently learning basics in mandatory class. However, after getting zero points in the final exam, I want to ask you what is wrong with this code which I'm trying to solve, spending 5 hours in a single question.

The expected answer is something like :

```
be = [34, 48, 66, 128, 220, ...]
the = [10, 12, 24, 33, 66, ...]
as = [1, 55, 88, ...]
```

The detailed problems I have to solve in this questions are as:

1. Remove all the pronouns.
2. Remove all the results more than 5 times

Let alone, however, I just don't even get the initial code to run because it loops like hundreds of thousand times, making the application go insane.

Any ideas to solve the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't clearly explained what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: There are quite a few errors in your code (e.g. function calls don't include a space, that is you need to call `open(...)` rather than `open (...)` etc., the same is true for indexing (`lines[i]` rather than `lines [i]`). You don't have to  save each result of a `replace` operation as a separate object etc etc. Also it is unclear what you are trying to do, and what your example shows (what do the numbers for `be`, `the`, `as` count?)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something.

```
wordlist = list(set(fhand_text10))
wordlist.sort()

for word in wordlist :
    appeartimes = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(lines)) :
        if word in lines [i] :
            count = count + 1
        if count > 5 :
            continue
        else:
            appeartimes.append(i+2)

if 5 > len(appeartimes) > 0 :
    print word, appeartimes
```

This gives me a list of word index with :

```
'Word' [row_number1, row_number2, row_number3]
```

but I still cannot find how to find exact word in the word list. For example, it still finds 'able' in 'vegetable', and re.match or re.search doesn't seem to work with list of words.

Comment: I used
`if re.search(r'\b' + word + r'\b', lines [i]):`
instead of
`if word in lines [i] :`

it worked!